# How would you carry out complete reduction of enone to form saturated alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, carbonyl-compounds

I have been reading some literature on enone reduction. Some conditions favour enol formation, others favour ketone formation. For example, using $\ce{NaBH4}$ with $\ce{CeCl3}$ selects the unsaturated alcohol (Luche Reaction).

For a general enone, would $\ce{NaBH4}$ be able to take you from enone to (saturated) alcohol? If so, mechanistically, would hydride attack start at the ketone (hard-hard pairing)?

Comment: Sodium borohydride generally affords the allylic alcohol though selectivity may vary depending on conditions and exact substrate.

Comment: I am still not 100% sure how to tackle this-I am asked to suggest reagents for the reduction of cyclohexenone to cyclohexanol but I can't find a procedure for this...maybe NaBH4 to make the enol, then reduce the alkene with hydrogen and catalyst?

Comment: Why not just hydrogenation and then borohydride reduction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own experience with Luche conditions is that they are fickle, and as likely to give you a mixture of 1,2 and 1,4 reduction products as not. For complete reduction of an enone I would go with Lithium triethyl borohydride to reduce the enone to ketone then sodium borohydride for ketone to alcohol. You can equally use catalytic hydrogenation for the enone reduction to ketone.